# What are the ferst 20 primes of the form $1+2\cdot 3^n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I need to find primes of the form $1+2\cdot 3^n$  for large $n$. Can somebody give me a program to find them?

Comment: What does "large" n mean to you? A table of the first 14 such primes is at https://oeis.org/A111974

Comment: See [Lucas primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test)

Comment: Presumably, you mean $1+2\cdot 3^n$? In US notation, $2.3=2+\frac{3}{10}$.

Comment: You do have $$1+2\cdot3^{11}\lt 10^6\lt1+2\cdot3^{12}$$ so you have to compute only $11$ numbers and examine if there is primality.

Comment: @Piquito what do you mean ??

Comment: none? $2.3^n=\frac{23}{10}\cdot\frac{23}{10}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{23}{10}$ and you're never gonna get a numerator divisible by $10$ since the numerator's only factors are powers of $23$. So $2.3^n$ is never gonna be an integer (unless $n$ isn't either, in which case, it's trivial to find $n$ with logarithms)

Comment: In the title I have read appeared the bound $10^6$.

Comment: @Jam $1+2.3^0=2$ is a prime.

Comment: I mean the ferst primes of the form    1+2×(3^n)

Comment: Per Jehad Jehad's Comment above, I've edited the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question if you meant to implement and understand the maths of [Lucas's primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test).

Otherwise, you should better ask on stackoverflow if you just want to run a for loop and call `isprime` function.